# What is more costly for a computer to compute (2*2) or (0.02*0.02)?

Tags: high-speed-computing

The title says it.
I was wondering if normalization has any effect on computing.
Does normalization effect computing?

Comment: Integer calculation is much faster than floating point, but I'm not sure what do you mean with normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is costlier to compute 0.02 * 0.02 compared to 2 * 2 has 2 * 2 is a single math operation where only one multiplication is involved.
Floating point number are stored has 2*10^-2 format(scientific notation). Therefore, two operations are involved here,

1. 2 * 2
2. (-2) + (-2)

Thus, the answer is computed as 4 * 10^(-4) or 0.0004.
Thus, 0.02 * 0.02 is costlier compared to 2*2.

Comment: Thanks, I guess when we normalize mathematical values of features  for machine learning we're increasing cost of computation. Am I right?